# FBX file import in Model Target Generator 10.16.3 or 10.17.4 results in model with colors only but no textures

Tags: vuforia

- I am new to the Vuforia SDK & tools.
- Successfully imported a 3D model target based on an FBX file into Model Target Generator 10.16.3 or 10.17.4.
- However, in Model Target Generator 10.16.3 only colors for surfaces are recognized after import. No textures. FBX opens fine with textures in 3ds Max and other tools.

**How can I achieve an import into Model Target Generator 10.16.3 or 10.17.4 which retains the textures?**

Thank you very much

Alexander

What I already tried **without** success:

### 3ds Max

- enabled texture export and correct axis, e.g. https://help.3drepo.io/en/articles/4768925-include-textures-in-fbx-files
- various FBX file format versions and combinations of other options
- OBJ file format

### SketchUp

- imported 3ds Max data, verified textures and exported as FBX from SketchUp

Comment: I updated the questions as I confirmed the issue still exists in Model Target Generator 10.17.4.

Comment: I would file a bug report here https://github.com/PTCInc/vuforia-engine including a sample fbx file that they can use to reproduce the problem

Comment: Already contacted Vuforia. Was instructured to ask right here at SO first.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Vuforia we were successfully able to use GLB file format instead of FBX file format. Importing GLB in Model Target Generator keeps the textures.

Thanks, Vuforia!